# In Turtle (Haskell), how can I get the output of a command, and do something with it?

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell beginner, trying to translate a shell script into a Turtle script, just as an exercise. In BASH, I'd get the output of some command like so: `cmdoutput=$(my-command -option 1 -option 2` and then I could do a `case` switch in BASH to echo out different messages or run different actions, depending on the value of `cmdoutput`. How can I achieve that in Haskell Turtle?

Edit: here's the shell script I'm trying to translate:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

export CLOCKSTRING=$(emacsclient --eval '(if (org-clocking-p)(org-clock-get-clock-string) -1)' 2>&1 )

case "$CLOCKSTRING" in
    "-1")
        echo "Off!" ;;
    *"server-start"*)
        echo "Off!" ;;
    *"ERROR"*)
        echo "No clock!" ;;
    *)
        echo ${CLOCKSTRING:3:30} ;
esac
```

And here's what I have so far with Turtle:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Turtle
import qualified Control.Foldl as Fold

translate :: Text -> Text
translate response = case response of
 "-1" -> "Got nothin"
 otherwise -> response

main = do
  let cmd2 = "emacsclient --eval '(if (org-clocking-p)(org-clock-get-clock-string) -1)'"

  emacsOut <- fold (inshell cmd2 empty) Fold.head
  print $ translate $ emacsOut
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inshell` to run a command and capture its output.

```
inshell "my-command -option 1 -option 2" empty
```

Note that that assumes you're in the `Shell` monad, not the `IO` monad. If you're in the latter, you'd need to consume it somehow, [such as by folding](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.5.15/docs/Turtle-Tutorial.html#g:11):

```
import qualified Control.Foldl as Fold
fold (inshell "echo abc\necho def" empty) Fold.list
```

Edit: Your attempt with `translate` was close. Try like this:

```
translate :: Maybe Line -> String
translate response = case lineToText <$> response of
 Just "-1" -> "Got nothin"
 otherwise -> show response
```

Comment: That's cool. But is there a way to do a `case` on the output of a function?

Comment: @Jonathan Bind it into a variable with `<-` and then case-match on said variable.

Comment: I updated my question with the code I have so far. I think maybe it's not working because I need to do error handling first? Or there's something else wrong.

Comment: @Jonathan Try the new `translate` function that I just edited into my answer.

Comment: Awesome. Could you say what the `<$>` is doing here?

Comment: @Jonathan It's also known as `fmap`, which is an operation on functors. It does something slightly different for every functor. I'm using it on the `Maybe` functor here, for which it lets you apply a function to the inside if it's `Just`. It's looking at what `response` is, and changing it to `Just (lineToText x)` if it's `Just x`, or leaving it as `Nothing` if it's `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shellStrict`, and following is my abstracted tool `shEval` which is  implemented via `shellStrict`:

```
shEval :: Partial => Text -> IO Text
shEval cmd = do
    (rst, out) <- Turtle.shellStrict cmd empty
    case rst of
        Turtle.ExitSuccess -> pure out
        Turtle.ExitFailure code -> terror ("shell process exit with non-zero code (" ++ tshow code ++ ")")
```